# SKAction Moveto not completing within the duration?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I am trying to make something like a clock with sweeping hands.

I pull the minutes from `NSDate`.

Then somewhat calculate a radian value and find an XY position where my sprite should move to in 1 min,

Then at the beginning of the next min I calculate the next XY position where my sprite should move to in that min.

so i have these codes inside the update function

```
//Get Current Minute
var currentTime = NSDate();
var nowCal = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.ISO8601)
var currMin = nowCal?.component(.minute, from: currentTime as Date)

//Print current minute        
print(currMin)

// slicing the circle into 60 segments and getting which angle in radians the sprite should move to in the next min
var minAng = (2*CGFloat.pi)/60 * CGFloat(currMin!)

//calculating point on the circle where the sprite should move to in the next min        
var newPt = CGPoint(x: (300 * cos(minAng)), y: -(300 * sin(minAng)))

//print out where the sprite currently is and where it should move to 
print(hand.position)
print(newPt)


//move the sprite to the new location over 60 seconds, making sure the movement is linear        
let moveHand = SKAction.move(to: newPt, duration: 60)
moveHand.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.linear
hand.run(moveHand)

//move another placeholder sprite to the final destination instantly to visualise movment by waiting for the moving sprite.
handToBe.run(SKAction.move(to: newPt, duration: 0))
```

Assuming i am understanding everything correctly, it should move through the segment in 1 minute, reaching the end of the segment before needing to move to the next segment.

however, my sprite never reaches the end of the segment before needing to move to the next segment. the printouts shows that it is always too slow.

is there something i am not understanding about `SKAction.move(to:)`, or is my logic flawed in this instance?

Comment: why don't you just use the rotateTo action?

Comment: i am not rotating. its a sprite that has to travel on a circular path.

i suppose i can make it a really big transparent sprite with a dot at one end but then there will be 2 issues.

I can't rotate the sprite and move it in a circle and it would be hard to scale.

Also, the point is i am trying to understand the duration issue in Moveto as a learning experiment, not trying to find an alternative method.

However i suspect rotate to by duration likely behaves similarly.

Comment: Yes it would be the same behavior

Comment: @Eivie Wrong usage of actions inside of `update:` method. What is the point of running an action with a duration of 60 seconds (or even 1 second) if `update:` method is called 60 times per seconds (ideally) ? I mean there is no `if` statement, so I assume that this code runs no matter what.

Comment: @Whirlwind i am using update method the same way i do in game design. is that not the purpose of update? 

i am hoping that the action that last 1/60 seconds will end just as the next frame starts and gives it the action for the next 1/60 second.

Comment: Wrong usage of actions anyways (IMO). You are creating a new instance of action 60 times per second to move a node from point A to point B. You should change position property of a node without using actions at all.

Comment: So just asign a new point to node.position inside of an update: method

Comment: @Whirlwind

yea, i reread my code over and over and realized i was calling action to go to a point in 60 seconds, 60 times a second.

i am assuming that is going to mess things up.

i tried getting more precision by reading a smaller measure of time for the angle, i.e using seconds when i want the action done in a min, slicing the circle thinner and using the move to action with duration 0.

that worked. but i might want to explore how to use repeat forever with pathing or using call action again.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the code from the `update` function and just run it in a function that you call yourself. `update` gets called every frame, so the sprite starts to move, then the next frame it is told to move to another position, so it now has two move actions it needs to run at the same time. The frame after that it has 3 move actions it needs to run, etc. This could mean that it never really reaches its first intended position because of the other move actions that are affecting it at the same time.

Comment: hmm i see what you mean. but wouldnt that would mean that the action that i have called to run for supposedly 1/60 of a second did not finish in the frame that lasted 1/60 of a second at 60 fps?

i could remove the code from the update function and try using repeat forever but that would mean implementing the path. i am hesistant about that because it sounds like it could complicate the code, and i am also unsure if it will provide the clockwork precision i am aiming for.

Comment: Yes, the action did not finish in the frame, since the action's duration was set to 60 seconds. I don't know if implementing the path will be necessary. You could just run the next move action after the first move action has completed, like run(someAction, completion: { callTheActionAgain() } )

Comment: i did not know such a function existed. i will explore that option as well.

actually when i said i set it to run for 1/60th of a second, i was mistaken

i reread my code and actually, i called for the action to go to the point in 60 seconds, 60 times a second.

is that going to cause issues?

Comment: I think that's the main reason why the code didn't behave as you had expected, i.e. the action was set to last 60 seconds. I would still avoid placing the code in the update function, because if the frame rate drops, you will lose the 1/60 second precision (e.g. instead of the update function getting called 60 times a second, it may be called 50 times a second, which means that the move action will only be executed 50 times in 1 second). Instead, maybe look at executing the action for 1/60 seconds and then call the next action after it has completed. Hope this helps!